# Impersonate in Windows Azure Webapplication to create Active Directory Account

Tags: asp.net, azure, impersonation

I am trying to develop an application that allows me to create Accounts on my active directory. The application is hosted over Azure.

So, to create an user from my Azure Webapplication, I need Impersonate myself as an authorized person (Service Account). Is this right?

Can you give me any code examples, how to accomplish this? Im not really familiar with this topic so I dont really know where to search.

Comment: you mean Azure Active Directory?

Comment: No. I want to create users on my on-prem Active Directory. I've created a Service Account for this case and now I need to Impersonate myself as this service account.